# Sonar-Gerrit Jenkins plugin not reporting issues on Gerrit

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gerrit, gerrit-trigger, sonar-gerrit

**Jenkins and SonarQube Environment Information**

```
Jenkins - 2.235.5
Gerrit Trigger - 2.31.0
Sonar Gerrit Plugin - 2.4.3
SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins - 2.12    
SonarQube Version -  6.7.7 (LTS).
```

**Configuration:** - Freestyle Job.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Jenkins Job Console log(Last few lines):-**

```
INFO: Performing issue tracking
INFO: 3270/3270 components tracked
INFO: Export issues to /jenkins-node/workspace/Gerrit-Test/.scannerwork/sonar-report.json
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
INFO: Executing post-job Final report
INFO: Turn debug info on to get more details (sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.verbose=true ...).
INFO: Task total time: 2:21.625 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2:22.428s
INFO: Final Memory: 71M/1470M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
Getting Sonar Report from: /jenkins-node/workspace/Gerrit-Test/.scannerwork/sonar-report.json
Report has loaded and contains 13752 issues
Issues to be commented: 0
Issues to be involved in score calculation: 0
Review has been sent
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Though build/analysis is completed successfully, However nothing is commented on Gerrit. Is it something missing in my jenkins job setting?

Comment: How are the advanced settings configurated ("Report new issues only?", "Add comments to changed lines only?", etc)?

Comment: Jenkins Job's `Review Settings` image added in question section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post comments issue:

SonarQube has found 13752 issues, but Is there some new issue in some changed line? I ask that because you have chosen to report (comment) only if new issues are found ("Report new issues only?" option) and only in changed lines ("affect changed lines only" option).

Post score issue:

You've chosen to use score "0" for "Score for no SonarQube violations found case" and for "Score for SonarQube violations found case". I think that with these options the plugin will never post the score.